# NicEdit and Imageshack : does Imageshack keep our images without account?

Tags: upload, account, nicedit, imageshack

I'm using NicEdit for uploading pictures. But I have heard that Imageshack doesn't keep images for a long time if we aren't registered. Is that true with Nicedit ?

Thank's !
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with NicEdit, but I've seen imageshack images become unavailable after they got hotlinked too much. It's rare though, and I've used imageshack for quite some years with very few problems. Never used an account.

But since they have been adding more restrictions over the past few months (trying to get people to create an account) I found myself using imgur.com more and more. I like it better than imageshack (the interface is easier, can upload multiple images etc). No account there either.

A site I can NOT recommend is tinypic.com. Been using that for a while as well, but images appeared to have randomly changed (i.e. the same link suddenly resulted in a completely different pictre). Happened quite a few times so I never use it anymore.

So, altogether I'd say imageshack is fine, but imgur remains my #1 pick to date.